# Android tap highlight always pink

Tags: android, css, hyperlink

i can't fix the problem. I'm testing website on Android smartphone and when i tap on links it becomes hotpink on a second.
I'm using styles:

```
::-moz-selection { background: #989898; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background: #989898; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }

a,a:hover,a:active,a:visited {-webkit-tap-highlight-color: #989898;}
```

But it doesn't work. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your css file

```
a:focus{}
```

in your reset.css `::-moz-selection{ background: #FF5E99;}` changes color code

Comment: a,a:hover,a:active,a:visited,a:focus {-webkit-tap-highlight-color: #989898;}
a:focus {background: #989898;} doesn't work too...

Comment: in your reset.css  ::-moz-selection{ background: #FF5E99;} changes color code